# background image in Sencha Architect

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Using Sencha Architect, How to display background image ? I wanna see background image in design view, so I can snapshot. I have tried two ways:

First using CSS resources and background CSS Property, that works when app is saved and view in chrome but there is no background in SA Design View.

Second, I tried to place image (as background) but can't add buttons on that image.

Please help me to view background image in SA Design View. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this:

http://docs.sencha.com/architect/2/#!/guide/resources

Add your CSS file to your Architect project and it will apply in the design view like this:

[image: snapshot]